# How to get height of FlatList element inside renderItem function in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native. I want to animate the deletion of `FlatList` Item on swiping to the left. I'm getting the values of swipe and able to delete the item but it is not smooth.

So, I'm using `Animated` API of react native and want to make the height of FlatList item 0 in 1000ms after swiping.

I'm using inputRange and outputRange. But I'm not able to get height of current element as height of all elements is dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the height of a view using the onLayout prop.

```
<View onLayout={(event) => {
  const {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  // do something here like set your initial animated value for the height
}} />
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#onlayout

Animating height is not the best approach as height animations are not performant. You may wish to animate a transform instead and animate the vertical scale of the view.

If you can use the Native driver for animations then they will be very performant 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations#using-the-native-driver

> Not everything you can do with Animated is currently supported by the
>   native driver. The main limitation is that you can only animate
>   non-layout properties: things like transform and opacity will work,
>   but flexbox and position properties will not.

This SO answer explain well how to perform a transform animation https://stackoverflow.com/a/45634834/5508175

My personal approach would be to fade out the contents of the view and then animate the vertical scale of the view to zero.